# Storing a specific part of a dict value into a string

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, bearer-token

```
import requests
import json

url = "********"

payload = json.dumps({
"username": "*****",
"password": "*****"
})
headers = {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)


#*** Convert response into a dictionary ***
r = json.loads(response.text)

# *** print the value of they key 'accessToken'
bearerToken = r['accessToken']
print(bearerToken)
```

**Output**

```
{'accessToken': 'e************************************', 'tokenType': 'Bearer'}
```

**What am I trying to achieve?**

Grab only the censored code after 'accessToken' and store the new Access Token in a string to use it in HTTP requests.

Note: 'accessToken' is a value of another key called accessToken. So the traditional method of printing the value of the key has already been used in the output shown above.

**Complete output:**

```
{
  "accessToken" : {
    "accessToken" : "e******************",
    "tokenType" : "Bearer"
  },
  "refreshToken" : {
    "id" : "6*************",
    "lastAccessedTime" : 1***********,
    "refreshToken" : "e*************"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can use substrings to accomplish what you want. If the length of the prefix is constant, then all you would need to do is use a slice with constant index,

In your example, it looks like you have an accessToken key, and inside that key is another dictionary holding a key that can change between entries. Assuming that you want the censored portion after e in accessToken, you can access that using:

```py
bearerToken = r['accessToken'][accessToken][1:]
```

This will give you the access token "******************", which is everything from index 1 onwards. If you just want the entire string, you can omit the [1:] portion.

Comment: When using the code piece you shared, the 2nd 'accessToken' returns the error: undefined variable

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question then. 

`Note: 'accessToken' is a value of another key called accessToken. So the traditional method of printing the value of the key has already been used in the output shown above.`


What I understood was that you have a key called "accessToken", and then another key that was for the dictionary stored inside of the key "accessToken". If this is not the case, just do

```python
bearerToken = r['accessToken']['accessToken'][1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to edit the code provided by yeeshue99, the 2nd value to 'accessToken' with the '' marks. the [1:] was also not needed.

**Solution**

```
bearerToken = r['accessToken']['accessToken']
```